# How to call setState or update value in InheritedWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Reproducible Code:**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: CountInheritedWidget(child: HomePage())));

class CountInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  CountInheritedWidget({Widget child}) : super(child: child);

  final Map<String, int> _map = {"count": 0};

  // getter
  int get value => _map["count"];

  // setter
  set value(int x) => _map["count"] = x; // is there anything like setState here?

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(CountInheritedWidget oldCounter) => true;

  static CountInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) => context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<CountInheritedWidget>();
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextWidget(),
            ButtonWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int count = CountInheritedWidget.of(context)?.value ?? -1;
    return Text("Count = $count");
  }
}

class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Increment"),
      onPressed: () {
        CountInheritedWidget counter = CountInheritedWidget.of(context);
        int count = counter?.value ?? -1;
        counter.value = ++count;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I'd like to update the value of `count` from `ButtonWidget`, I am sure it is getting updated in the `CounterInheritedWidget` class but it isn't reflecting on the screen. How can I call `setState` or something like that from `InheritedWidget`?

Any help will be appreciated, I am newbie to Flutter and Dart so having tough time in solving this kind of issue. Thank you and have a great day.

---

**Note:**  I am not looking for some plugins like `Provider`, `ScopedModel`, `Redux` for this kinda work.

Answer (score 13):

InheritedWidgets cannot do that. They are completely immutable with no mechanism for triggering updates.

If you want to emit updates, you will have to combine your InheritedWidget with a StatefulWidget, typically done in such way:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;

  @override
  MyState createState() => MyState();
}

class MyState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String name;
  int age;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyInherited(
      name: name,
      age: age,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Where `MyInheritedWidget` is:

```dart
class MyInherited extends InheritedWidget {
  MyInherited({
    Key key,
    this.name,
    this.age,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final String name;
  final int age;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyInherited oldWidget) {
    return name != oldWidget.name && age != oldWidget.age;
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(IntProperty('age', age));
    properties.add(StringProperty('name', name));
  }
}
```

Yup. That's verbose. Which is why `provider` exists.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that, can you also update your example to reflect mine?

Comment: InheritedWidget is just like context in react js

Comment: The exmplanation does not reflect the question of updating the value via usage of the InheritedWidget.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyStateful(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              MyCounter(),
              MyButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// MyStateful and MyInherited together act like a Provider
class MyStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStateful({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;

  @override
  MyState createState() => MyState();
}

class MyState extends State<MyStateful> {
  int _count = 0;

  void increment() {
    setState(() {
      _count += 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyInherited(
      count: _count,
      increment: this.increment,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

// Whenever state values are changes a new MyInherited is created
// with new parameters.
class MyInherited extends InheritedWidget {
  MyInherited({
    Key? key,
    required this.count,
    required this.increment,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final int count;
  final void Function() increment;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyInherited oldWidget) {
    return count != oldWidget.count;
  }

  static MyInherited of(BuildContext context) {
    final MyInherited? result =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInherited>();
    assert(result != null, 'No MyInherited found in context');
    return result!;
  }
}

class MyCounter extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCounter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Count: ${MyInherited.of(context).count}');
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        MyInherited.of(context).increment();
      },
      child: const Text('Increment'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this snippet:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyWidget());
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.blue,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyStateFulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStateFulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStateFulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStateFulWidget> createState() => _MyStateFulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStateFulWidgetState extends State<MyStateFulWidget> {
  Color color = Colors.red;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FrogColor(
      color: color,
      child: Builder(
        builder: (innerContext) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                color = Colors.blue;
              });
            },
            child: Text(
              'Hello frog',
              style: TextStyle(color: FrogColor.of(innerContext).color),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FrogColor extends InheritedWidget {
  final Color color;

  const FrogColor({
    super.key,
    required this.color,
    required super.child,
  });

  static FrogColor? maybeOf(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<FrogColor>();
  }

  static FrogColor of(BuildContext context) {
    final FrogColor? result = maybeOf(context);
    assert(result != null, 'No FrogColor found in the context');
    return result!;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(FrogColor oldWidget) => color != oldWidget.color;
}
```